# Searching between two BIGINT

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IPS_INTEGERS](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [network_start_integer] [bigint] NULL,
    [network_last_integer] [bigint] NULL,
    [connection_type] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

It has about 360k registers and querying it repeatedly many times by second.
I need the following query optimized; currently it completes in 8 ms and I'd like to improve that.

```
SELECT connection_type 
FROM   IPS_INTEGERS 
WHERE  network_start_integer <= @IP 
AND    network_last_integer >= @IP
```

The `@IP` value has the C# `System.Int64` data type.

I have tried different indexing approaches but none giving the the expected optimization.

Currently using the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IPS_include_connection] ON [dbo].[IPS_INTEGERS]
(
    [network_start_integer] ASC,
    [network_last_integer] ASC
) INCLUDE ([connection_type])
```

Here's [the link to the estimated query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkH6R9npZ).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you have some implicit conversions to BIGINT going on.  Make sure @IP is defined as `BIGINT`.

Comment: It is a `System.Int64` called from c# code, is it correct right?

Comment: Can you describe what isn't happening that you'd like to happen? I've read your question and the comments and can't quite figure out what success looks like to you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query, just wanted to reduce timing due that it's being called hundred of times by second. I have a tool mesuring query times and it says this one is the slowest one (about 8ms) vs others I have that are less than 1 ms

Comment: @JurgenHarms alright, crazy question: what are queries waiting on for those 8ms?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik sorry, I have no clue...

Comment: Try the index with `network_last_integer` as a leading column: 

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IPS_inv_include_connection] ON [dbo].[IPS_INTEGERS]
    (   
        [network_last_integer] ASC,
        [network_start_integer] ASC
    ) INCLUDE ([connection_type])

 it can make difference similarly to intervals problem

Comment: @sepupic It gives even worse results in terms of timing

Comment: Did you just create it and server used it instead of your index or it was not chosen by server and you forced it using a hint?

Comment: @sepupic it wasn't chosen by server

Comment: How fast is the disk I/O?  Are you running from solid state?  How much of the table in question is loaded into memory?

Comment: You may be able to get a little better performance by throwing this into an [In-Memory OLTP Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization) if you're running SQL 2014 or later, but honestly, aside from the implicit conversion against the parameter it doesn't look like a poorly performing plan at all.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14894/3690

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values for the columns?

Comment: what is the expected performance?
Try to change the datatype for [network_start_integer] and [network_end_integer] from bigint to int and see if there is any deference

Comment: Convert_implication can be removed DECLARE @ip BIGINT = 1234

Comment: any conclusion ? i think querying 360k rows repeatedly every second is itself wrong.plz update.